# Fetch data from database using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to fetch data from database using MySQLi. But I am having an error in it. Please review my code and give me suggestions to improve it.

Code from config.php:

```
   public function select_data_from_db($table_name ,$run){
   $stmt=$run->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name); 
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   $total_count=$result->num_rows;
   $result= array();
  if($total_count>0){
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $result[] = $row;
  }
  }
  return $result;
 }
```

Code from index.php :

```
    <?php
   $myrow=$obj->select_data_from_db("home_slider"); ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo  $myrow['id']; ?> </td>
  <td><?php echo  $myrow['title']; ?> </td>
  <td><?php echo  $myrow['description']; ?> </td>
  </tr>
```

error which i am getting :

Warning: Missing argument 2 for main::select_data_from_db(), called in D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\slider_fetch_data.php on line 24 and defined in D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\config.php on line 113

Notice: Undefined variable: conn in D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\config.php on line 115

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\config.php on line 115

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated try to use mysqli_*  and show your database connection code too

Comment: Every message is caused from the first, you never successfully create a connection. Did you set up a password for the user you are logging in as?

Comment: yeah ...first error is gone..thanks:)

Comment: $result[] = $record;    it should be change to  $result[] = $row;

Comment: Update the question with the new code and error message(s).

Comment: i updated the question..please check

Comment: mysqli_query() first parameter is connection object second parameter is query  . still  your mixing mysqli_* with mysql  *while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))*

Comment: yes i correct it.

Comment: did you checked my below answer @varsha

Comment: yes ..i am following it

Comment: all your issue fixed ? @varsha

Comment: can you show the whole class instead  a single  function . @varsha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comment `yeah ...first error is gone..thanks:)` still you have some issue with your code .

**1st** :   `$result[] = $record;` you need to push the `$row` in array instead of `$record`

```
 $result[] = $row;
```

**2nd** :  Function will return the array you need to loop it to get the each row like this

**3rd** : Remove `$` sign from `array` index

```
<?php
   $myrow=$obj->select_data_from_db("home_slider");
 ?>

  <?php if(count($myrow)>0){ 
            foreach($myrow as $row){ ?>
   <tr>
  <td><?php echo  $row['id']; ?> </td>
  <td><?php echo  $row['title']; ?> </td>
  <td><?php echo  $row['description']; ?> </td>
 </tr>
 <?php } }

?>
```

**4th** : use prepared statement to avoid sql injection

```
public function select_data_from_db($table_name,$conn)
{

      $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name); 
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->get_result();
      $total_count = $result->num_rows;
      $result = array();
      if($total_count>0)
      {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
      }

      return $result;
 }
```

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions
>   were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: i am having these errors

Comment: update your post with updated code and post the error too @varsha

Comment: yes...i have update it

Comment: you need to pass the connection object in function call too like this $myrow=$obj->select_data_from_db("home_slider",$conn); @varsha

Comment: I having these errors:

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: run in D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\slider_fetch_data.php on line 24

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\config.php on line 115

Answer (score 0):

First you should establish the Connection from server. We are using **mysqli_connect**. For Example below the example,

```
private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "root";
private $password = "";
private $database = "DB_NAME";
private $conn;

function connectDB(){
$conn =    mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
return $conn;
}

public function select_data_from_db($table_name){
$query=mysqli_query($this->conn,"SELECT * FROM ".$table_name); 
$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$result[] = $row;
}
return $result;
}
```

Code from index.php **Single Record only display** :

```
<?php
$myrow=$obj->select_data_from_db("home_slider");?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo  $myrow['id']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo  $myrow['title']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo  $myrow['description']; ?> </td>
</tr>
```

Code from index.php **Multi Record displaying code** :

```
<?php
$myrow=$obj->select_data_from_db("home_slider");
foreach($myrow as $key)
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo  $key['id']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo  $key['title']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo  $key['description']; ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```